# i installed ubuntu in a different drive and windows was already there in another drive

Tags: windows

i installed Ubuntu in a different drive and windows was already there in another drive at first Ubuntu worked and windows was not being opened and now i cant open even Ubuntu and windows. can u please help me opening Ubuntu using bios?

Answer (score 0):

Open the bios (Normally your delete key) and set the boot order to begin with your Ubuntu hard drive. When grub loads and offers a few ubuntu options, pick Ubuntu -(Recovery mode). A menu should load up, select update grub and hopefully that should allow you to select windows or Ubuntu at the grub menu rather than having to worry about the bios.